# Using XmlRpc in C++ and Windows

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, xml-rpc

I need to use XmlRpc in C++ on a Windows platform.  Despite the fact that my friends assure me that XmlRpc is a "widely available standard technology", there are not many libraries available for it.  In fact I only found one library to do this on Windows, (plus another one that claims "you'll have to do a lot of work to get this to compile on Windows).  The library I found was Chris Morley's "XmlRpc++".  However, it doesn't have support for SSL.

My question therefore is:  what library should I be using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've written my own C++ library.  It's available at sourceforge:
[xmlrpcc4win](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlrpcc4win/)

The reason I wrote it rather than using Chris Morley's was that:

- The Windows "wininet.lib" library gives you all the functionality for handling Http requests, so I'd rather use that.  As a result, I only needed 1700 LOC.
- "wininet.lib", and therefore my implementation, supports HTTPS
- Chris Morley's use of STL containers was quite inefficient (Chris, mail me if you read this).

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to try that out. I have to admit though that I'm rather scared by this part in the TimXmlRpc.cpp file:


    #define not  !


    #define or  ||


    #define and  &&

Comment: Small update, I've been using this library with great success and it was very easy to implement. Highly recommended for anyone needing XmlRpc on Windows.

Comment: @TimCooper Does it support any way to make non-sync xmlrpc calls ?

Comment: I've just tried Tim's "XmlRpc C++ for Windows" with Infusionsoft and by golly it works! Gotta pay close attention to how Infusionsoft nests structs within arrays, though.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your lib! It doesn't seem to support Unicode though. Encoding is not specified in XML tag (hence defaults to UTF8). Client program must then convert strings to/from UTF8 before passing to the lib. Not very convenient. Also, the Release version of the project does not compile. I guess this one is not big an issue though since we use the source code only (and not the project). There are also strcpy / sprintf calls subject to buffer overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Until I wrote my own library, (see above) here was my answer:

Currently, the [XmlRpc++ library](http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/) by Chris Morley is the only public domain/LPGL XmlRpc implementation for C++ on Windows.

There are a couple of C++ implementations for Linux, either of which could be presumably easily ported to Windows, but the fact seems to be that no-one has yet done so and made it publicly available.  Also, as eczamy says, "The XML-RPC specification is somewhat simple and it would not be difficult to implement your own XML-RPC client."

I'm using Chris Morley's library successfully, despite having had to find and fix quite a number of bugs.  The [Help Forum](http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?forum_id=240495) for this project seems to be somewhat active, but no-one has fixed these bugs and done a new release.  I have been in correspondence with Chris Morley and he has vague hopes to do a new release, and he has contributed to this stackOverflow question (see below/above) and he claims to have fixed most of the bugs, but so far he has not made a release that fixes the many bugs.  The last release was in 2003.

It is disappointing to me that a supposed widely supported (and simple!) protocol has such poor support on Windows + C++.  Please can someone reading this page pick up the baton and e.g. take over XmlRpc++ or properly port one of the Linux implementations.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of implementations of the XML-RPC [implementations](http://www.xmlrpc.com/directory/1568/implementations), some in C++, but most in other languages. For example, besides XmlRpc++ there is also [XML-RPC for C and C++](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/). Here is a [HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XML-RPC-HOWTO/xmlrpc-howto-c.html) on how the XML-RPC for C and C++ library can be used.

The XML-RPC specification is somewhat simple and it would not be difficult to implement your own XML-RPC client. Not to mention, it would also be possible to take an existing XML-RPC implementation in C and bring into your C++ project.

The XML-RPC [home page](http://www.xmlrpc.com/) also provides a lot of useful information.

Comment: The "XML-RPC for C and C++" library does not work on Windows - I quote:  "...but the fact is that it probably won't work out-of-the-box on your Windows system."

That means that there's only one library for C++ that runs on Windows, i.e. Chris Morley's, and it doesn't have SSL support.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to note a couple of items:

- The source in the cvs repository for XmlRpc++ has support for OpenSSL (although I have not tried it, it was contributed by another developer).
- Most of the reported bugs are fixed in cvs; I don't have access to a linux machine at the moment, so I haven't made an official release.
- [XmlRpc++](http://xmlrpcpp.sourceforge.net/) is not public domain. It is copyrighted and licensed (LGPL).

Thanks,
Chris Morley

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get Tim's version of xml rpc working with https and with basic username / password authentication.

For the authentication:

1) the username and password need to be passed to the InternetConnect(...) function

2) an http request header of "Authorization: Basic base64encoded(user:pass)" needs to be added prior to sending the HttpSendRequest(...) command.

Comment: can you send me your modified source code?  I'll review and then put into the sourceforge version.  You can reach me on tim@edval.com.au